# Having troubles creating an iterator for my own list

Tags: java, iterator

My list looks like this:

```
public class SList<A> implements Iterable<A> 
{
    private Listelem head;
    private Listelem current;
    private boolean listEmpty;

    private class Listelem 
    {
        private A value;
        private Listelem next;

        private Listelem(A val) 
        {
            this.value = val;
            this.next  = null;
        }
        private Listelem() 
        {
            this.next  = null;
        }

        public void setValue(A val) 
        {
            this.value = val;
        }
        public A getValue() 
        {
            return this.value;
        }
        public void setSuccessor(Listelem next)
        {
            this.next = next;
        }
        public Listelem getSuccessor() 
        {
            return this.next;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to create an Iterator for this List but I am having some troubles.
In SList I am doing this:

```
@Override
public Iterator<A> iterator() {
    Iterator<A> it = new Iterator<A>() {

        this.current = this.head;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
           boolean hasNext = true;
           if( this.current.getSucessor == null )
           {
               hasNext = false;
           }
           return hasNext;
        }

        @Override
        public A next() {
            A next       = this.current.getValue;
            this.current = this.current.getSuccessor();
            return next;
        }

        @Override
        public void remove() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    };
    return it;
}
```

I can`t reference this.current or this.head. I am wondering why this is not working, since I am in the same class.

Comment: Too much code, can you at least point to the bit you are stuck on? Where is it not letting you reference it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply forgot to declare a `current` field in your Iterator. And the head of the list should be accessed with `SList.this.head`, or simply with `head`. `this` refers to the Iterator instance. Not to the list. You should use a non-anonymous class:

```
@Override
public Iterator<A> iterator() {
    return new MyListIterator();
}

private class MyListIterator implements Iterator<A> {
    private Listelem current;

    private MyListIterator() {
        this.current = head;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
       return this.current.getSucessor != null;
    }

    @Override
    public A next() {
        A next       = this.current.getValue;
        this.current = this.current.getSuccessor();
        return next;
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new Iterator with `new`, therefore you are in a anonymous inner class of your class. Try with `SList.this.current`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `SList.this.head`. You're attempting to reference a field that doesn't exist in the `Iterator` subclass you're defining.

Instead, you want to reference the `head` field of the enclosing `SList` class. That's what you can obtain by using the snippet I posted in the beginning.

Comment: The current element of the iterator shouldn't be in the list. It should be a field of the iterator object.